# Java: визуализация графов

Tags: java, графика, графы, поиск-библиотек

Хочу на java побаловаться с визуализацией графов.
Цель: набить руку в java.
Подскажите какая графическая библиотека для этого подойдёт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется для вашей задачи вполне хватит встроенных средств java, я бы посоветовал попробовать javafx, ибо она "стильная, модная, молодежная" по сравнению со swing'ом. Так даже не знаю что посоветовать из сторонних, знаю, что есть qtjambi, но сам не пробовал, swt  монструозно для вашей задачи

Answer (score 2):

JUNG или JGraph , на Ваше усмотрение :)
От себя , добавлю , JUNG - полностью бесплатная библиотека , а JGraph - коммерческая. Однако , в библиотеке JGraph (которую мне не удалось использовать) реализовано больше алгоритмов для работы с графами , чем в JUNG(Алгоритм Дейкстры , Флойда - Уоршалла , Гамильтонов путь и т.д.
Функционал этих библиотек полностью соответствует Swing.